# using LIKE %% with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, i used "LIKE"  with "LEFT JOIN" and it works fine.

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tasks t 
                     LEFT JOIN users u 
                     ON t.allowed_countries LIKE u.country 
                     WHERE u.username = '$username'");
```

but when i'm try to use "LIKE %%" instead of using "LIKE" then it gives me error

```
LIKE '%" u.country "%'
```

Can anybody tell me the problem please?

Thank you.

Comment: beware that using wildcards like this in SQL is likely to have significant performance issues. You won't notice it on a small data set, but as your data grows, it will slow down because it will have to scan the entire table to find matching records. You would be better off having a sub-table so that each allowed country for each task is in a separate record, and also link them using record IDs rather than the full country name string. Google 'many-to-many relationships' to find out more about how to do this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

USE `concat` as % is a char literal.

```
LIKE concat('%',u.country,'%')
```