# Left Join using a matrix field in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field in one table that needs to be related to other table, but the values inside are comma separated, and need to relate every each one of them with their names on the table_b

reference table

```
table_a
cod_item | Order
1,2,3    | 1
2,4,5    | 2
2        | 3
5,6,7    | 1
```

second table:

```
table_b
cod_item | Name
1        | prod_1
2        | prod_2
3        | prod_3
4        | prod_4 ...
```

the result needed is:

```
ORDER | CONTENT
1     | 1 - prod_1, 2 - prod_2, 3 - prod_3
2     | 2 - prod_2, 4 - prod_4, 5 - prod_5
```

and so on.. or something like it.. I just lost how to do this reference...the tables are very very large...

Thanks!!

Comment: Is column `cod_item` in `table_a`  comma separated?

Comment: I recall doing something like this a while ago using LIKE in the LEFT JOIN. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324611/using-like-with-left-join

Comment: cod_item is comma separated! need to reach every each one of this values and get their names...

Answer (score 1):

SQLFiddle is down so I can't test but I think you can use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function with a `CONCAT` in the `JOIN`.

```
SELECT a.order, CONCAT(b.cod_item, ' - ', GROUP_CONCAT(b.name)) CONTENT
FROM table_a a
INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.cod_item LIKE CONCAT('%', b.cod_item, '%')
```

Comment: The result is the same as above answer, i tested both with same result...brings more names than itens...

Answer (score 1):

You can use GROUP BY GROUP_CONCAT

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_a
>     (`cod_item` varchar(5), `Order` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table_a
>     (`cod_item`, `Order`)
> VALUES
>     ('1,2,3', 1),
>     ('2,4,5', 2),
>     ('2', 3),
>     ('5,6,7', 1)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table_b
>     (`cod_item` int, `Name` varchar(10))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table_b
>     (`cod_item`, `Name`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'prod_1'),
>     (2, 'prod_2'),
>     (3, 'prod_3'),
>     (4, 'prod_4')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `Order`,GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(b.`cod_item` ,' - ', b.`Name`) ORDER BY b.`cod_item`)
> FROM table_a a LEFT JOIN table_b b ON  FIND_IN_SET(b.`cod_item`,a.`cod_item`)
> GROUP BY `Order`
> ```
>
> ```
> Order | GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(b.`cod_item` ,' - ', b.`Name`) ORDER BY b.`cod_item`)
> ----: | :------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     1 | 1 - prod_1,2 - prod_2,3 - prod_3                                         
>     2 | 2 - prod_2,4 - prod_4                                                    
>     3 | 2 - prod_2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=707d6e5c40beb72081981568f2361c60)*

Comment: Sorry, that does not work for me. the result is: 1,2,3 - prod_1,prod_2,prod_3,prod_4...so on...

Comment: i don't understand you comment. what do you mean by `the result is: 1,2,3 - prod_1,prod_2,prod_3,prod_4`so you want another output or do you get such output

Comment: also your sample has two orders with number one, are you sure that your data model is correct?     ('1,2,3', 1) and    ('5,6,7', 1) so a group by order would make that result for that you need different order numbers

Comment: Was my mistake. I fogot to use the GROUP by in the end.

Comment: Actually, it works this way. It brings up first the cod_iten then a separator '-' and then, in order, the names of each iten. I'll try using this way !! THANKS!

Comment: @Datafinder is there a problem ?